# Grey/Low contrast background on Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In google's web SDK for Google Maps, you can "Style" the map and make it somewhat grey.
I can't find a way to do the same on Android, did I miss something ? If they didn't provide an API for that, is there a way to desaturate the MapView using an Overlay for example ?

Comment: I suppose you could overlay a view over the fragment with some transparency...??

Comment: and my suggestion was to put a view (framelayout for example) ontop of the mapfragment to cover (overlay) the mapfragment in your layout xml of the activity

Comment: Yes I understand your suggestion but I fail to see how it answers my question : setting transparency on the framelayout will do nothing to desaturate the underlying base layer.